# geth export file name

Tags: go-ethereum

I have a private etherum node setup in local machine and I want to try geth export command. For this I need to specify the .rlp file . Can anybody help me to locate the .rlp file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to to specify name of an existing file.  You need to specify name of the file to export blockchain data into.  Geth will create this file and fill it with information.

So you do:

```
geth export my-file.rlp
```

to dump blockchain data into file `my-file.rlp`, and then, probably on another machine, you do:

```
geth import my-file.rlp
```

to load blockchain data from file created by `geth export` command on first machine

Answer (score 0):

in addition to also @Mikhail Vladimirov, there are official wiki here:
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Backup-&-restore

other options to export until specific block numbers(ex: from zero to 29999 to `my-file.rlp` file),

You can do :

```
geth export my-file.rlp 0 29999
```